# An action on executable's library load

Tags: c++, linker, elf

Let's say, I have an executable `a.out`. It has shared libraries `libcrypto.so`, `libmylib.so`. I'd like to make some action at every of these libs load. Is there some function I can add my code to? So I will define some function inside my executable and it will be called twice for this example.

I'm aware of `__attribute__ ((constructor))`, but it should be defined for every library specifically, which is not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean like hooking `dlopen`?

Comment: @PeterT, yes. Is there a more conforming way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to make some action at every of these libs load. Is there some function I can add my code to?

Your code, no. But you could `LD_PRELOAD` a `dlopen` interposer.

Example:

```
// foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor))
void ctor()
{
  printf("In %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

```
// main.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf(">>> main\n");
  dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  dlopen("./bar.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  printf("<<< main\n");

  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o foo.so foo.c
gcc -shared -fPIC -o bar.so foo.c
gcc main.c -ldl
./a.out
>>> main
In foo.c:6
In foo.c:6
<<< main
```

Now let's add a `dlopen` interposer:

```
// dlopen_preload.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void* (*FN)(const char *, int);

void *dlopen(const char *fname, int flags)
{
  FN real_dlopen = (FN)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "dlopen");
  void *ret = real_dlopen(fname, flags);

  printf("my dlopen(%s, 0x%x) -> %p\n", fname, flags, ret);

  return ret;
}
```

```
gcc -shared -o dlopen_preload.so dlopen_preload.c
LD_PRELOAD=./dlopen_preload.so ./a.out
>>> main
In foo.c:6
my dlopen(./foo.so, 0x1) -> 0x565039670690
In foo.c:6
my dlopen(./bar.so, 0x1) -> 0x565039670c90
<<< main
```

Voilà.